# Update() loop in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to add a recoil system to my fps game.

Let's say my weapon has a recoil of 1000.
Every time i update my player rotation (in the fps controller script) i am substracting a (recoil / 100) to the Y rotation:

```
playerCam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation - (GunManager.currentGunRecoil / 100), desiredX, 0);
```

it works fine to this point.

To smoothly reduce the recoil over time i have a code in the Update() method of my GunManager script which lowers the recoil value by 5 every frame.
The problem is it look like the code runs every once in a second.

I have also put a PRINT() inside the Update() and it prints the text just fine.

```
void Update()
{
    if (0 < GunManager.currentGunRecoil)
    {
        GunManager.currentGunRecoil -= 5;
    }
    else
    {
        GunManager.currentGunRecoil = 0;
    }

    print("UPDATE!");
    
    //other code
}
```

Notes: yes my fps controller is updating the rotation every frame too
and i have tried using FixedUpdate() which didnt help me

recording:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NWkI.jpg

Comment: Your gun recoil value (1000) will become 0 on or after 200th frame (200th call to Update). If you are running at speed of 60 FPS, it takes more than 3 seconds. Although I am not much sure about this.

Comment: yeah but camera should go back to the starting rotation after those 3 seconds

Comment: Debug and print the localRotation after each frame, maybe you will find some issue. One thing which is weird though, are you passing desiredX position to Y rotation in that Quaternion function?

Comment: yeah desiredX is MouseY axis

Comment: Recommend you to rename the variable appropriately to avoid any confusion to others and yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to add Time.deltaTime to your code? Not sure it will fix but it will smooth the experience based on the framerate.

```
lowRecoil=5;

void Update()
{
    if (0 < GunManager.currentGunRecoil)
    {
        GunManager.currentGunRecoil -= lowRecoil*Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        GunManager.currentGunRecoil = 0;
    }

    print("UPDATE!");
    
    //other code
}
```

But I guess the issue it is in this:

```
playerCam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation - (GunManager.currentGunRecoil / 100), desiredX, 0);
```

maybe you need to specify how you store xRotation and when. Try to print this statement in the Update:

```
Debug.Log(xRotation - (GunManager.currentGunRecoil / 100))
```

and see if actually does something.